# how to encode a dataframe table to json

Tags: python, datatables

I have a flask function that I create a plotly chart then pass via plotly encoder.

Is there something similar for datatables library? I want to pass both the fig and a table object into my json for a javascript function to parse later.

Here is my current code:

```
def drawtieringchart(service='All'):
    fig = create_tiering_scatter(service)
    graphJSON = json.dumps(fig, cls=plotly.utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder)
    generallogger.info(graphJSON)
    return graphJSON
```

I want something like this:

```
def drawtieringchart(service='All'):
    fig = create_tiering_scatter(service)
    graphJSON = json.dumps(fig, cls=plotly.utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder)
    df = somedata
    dfJson = json.dumps(df, cls=ENCODER HERE?
    final_JSON = COMBINE BOTH JSONS
    return final_JSON
```

Comment: pandas DataFrame has a [to_json method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved it:

```
def drawtieringchart(service='All'):
    fig = create_tiering_scatter(service)
    graphJSON = json.dumps(fig, cls=plotly.utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder)
    df=tiering_table(service)
    dfJson = df.to_json(orient='records')
    merged_dict = {
        "graphJSON": json.loads(graphJSON),
        "dfJson": json.loads(dfJson)
    }
    final_JSON = json.dumps(merged_dict)
    return final_JSON
```

In my jquery `$.getJSON` statement I reference each object list this `result.graphJSON` or `result.dfJson`:

```
<script>
    // callback function for rendering chart
    function cb(selection) {
        displayloadingcontainer("loaderContainer");
        $.getJSON({url: "/tieringcallback", data: { 'data': selection }})
            .done(result => {
            Plotly.react('chart', result.graphJSON, {responsive: true});
            $('#tiering_table').DataTable().clear().destroy();
            $('#tiering_table tbody').append(result.dfJson.map(item =>
                $('<tr>').append($('<td>').text(item.Name), $('<td>').text(item['Primary Service']), $('<td>').text(item.Value), $('<td>').text(item.Risk))
            ));
            $('#tiering_table').DataTable({});
            })
            .always(() => hideloadingcontainer("loaderContainer"));
    }
  </script>
```